# Css selector when one class is present and not both classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to do something like this `.horizontal-nav:not(.horizontal-nav.responsive-nav-enabled)`

i.e. I want to apply styles of `.horizontal-nav` only if the div does not have the `.responsive-nav-enabled` class. If it has both classes then the styles of `.horizontal-nav` must not apply. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.horizontal-nav:not(.responsive-nav-enabled)` to get the desired result:

```css
.horizontal-nav {
  height: 20px;
  border: thin solid;
}

.horizontal-nav:not(.responsive-nav-enabled) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='horizontal-nav'></div>
<div class='horizontal-nav responsive-nav-enabled'></div>
```

The problem with your original selector is that it is invalid and rejected by the browser. [`:not`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#negation) accepts a [simple selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) while `.horizontal-nav.responsive-nav-enabled` is a sequence of simple selectors.

Comment: "It's like flag && !flag which will always evaluate to false." No, that would only be the case with `.A:not(.A)`. Salman A is right - the problem is not the logic but that the syntax is just not (yet) supported.